# Помогите пожалуйста с функцией поворота в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Могу ли я сделать так, что-бы изображение `pygame.transform.rotate(image, +1)` поворачивалось не на конкретный градус, а к примеру становилось на один градус больше. Т.е. было 5 градусов, а после выполнения стало 6, потом 7 и т.д.

Comment: Завести переменную в которой хранить текущий угол, при повороте - менять значение.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Что-то не додумался.